# How to make EntityManager works properly in DAO Factories?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, dao, openejb

I want to implement DAO pattern described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) with EclipseLink and OpenEJB. The first try with Figure 9.1 listed in link works fine. The code is like:

```
// CustomerDAO
@Local
public interface CustomerDAO {
    Customer findCustomer(String id);
}

// OracleCustomerDAO
@Stateless
@Local(CustomerDAO.class)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class OracleCustomerDAO implements CustomerDAO {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MY_EJB")
    private EntityManager em;

    public Customer findCustomer(String id) {
        return em.find(Customer.class, id);
    }
}
```

And in my service:

```
public class CustomerService implements CustomerServiceLocal {
    @EJB
    CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    public Customer findCustomer(String id) {
        return customerDAO.findCustomer(id);
    }
}
```

However, when I want to adapt Factory pattern, I can't figure out what's the correct way to do it. I wrote the code as the tutorial in the link and add two classes like this:

```
// DAOFactory
public abstract class DAOFactory {
    public abstract CustomerDAO getCustomerDAO();

    public enum Factory {
        ORACLE;
    }

    public static DAOFactory getDaoFactory(Factory whichFactory) {
        switch (whichFactory) {
        case ORACLE:
            return new OracleDAOFactory();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

// OracleDAOFactory
public class OracleDAOFactory extends DAOFactory {

    @Override
    public CustomerDAO getCustomerDAO() {
        return new OracleCustomerDAO();
    }

}
```

And I modify my service to this:

```
public class CustomerService implements CustomerServiceLocal {

    public Customer findCustomer(String id) {

        CustomerDAO customerDAO = DAOFactory.getDaoFactory(Factory.ORACLE).getCustomerDAO();

        return customerDAO.findCustomer(id);
    }
}
```

And this gives me a **NullPointerException**. When I trace the code with debugger, I found that `EntityManager` in `OracleCustomerDAO` is `null`. I think it's because I didn't do any `@EJB` injection in my new service, but I have no idea where can I put that `@EJB` injection.

So what's the proper way to inject an EntityManager with DAO Factories Pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for EJB to behave like EJB, you should no create them.  The EJB container is responsible to create them an make sure every decoration (transaction, injection) is correctly apply.

The EJB container is already implementing the factory pattern for you.  You should use its functionality to get a particular implementation (I have not experience with stand alone openEJB but in a full Java EE environment CDI and JNDI are providing the needed functionality).

It seems you should be able to use JNDI to retrieve the expected EJB.

This code should work if the name of the EJB is by default the class name:

```
CustomerDAO friend = (CustomerDAO) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/OracleCustomerDAO");
```

([full doc](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/lookup-of-ejbs/README.html))

For the CDI way, you can use its alternative mechanism ([TommEE doc](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/cdi-alternative-and-stereotypes/README.html)).

A little word about patterns.  They should be use to fix a pain point.  The J2EE patterns have been documented to overcome the limitation of J2EE.  In future release of Java EE, they introduce element that implements the different pattern in a event more usable way.  JAP is part of it.

JPA is an implementation of the [Domain Store pattern](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/DomainStore.htm). In the Domain Store diagram you can clearly see that it already includes DAO. So what is the point to create DAO on top of a abstraction that already include DAO?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll read the docs and try to modify my code to make it works (and I'll accept the answer if I succeed, or I'll update the status in comment). In the pattern part, I read many topics about how JPA killed DAO or something like that, and there are many different opinions about this. I am still not sure is DAO pattern good or not with JPA, maybe someday the company want to get rid of JPA, and DAO pattern will be easier to refactor because it separate logical part and the data manipulation part?

Comment: If you replace JPA with other framework, 9.99% chances that your "DAO" abstraction will not work any more and you will need to update the DAO interfaces and the business logic using it.  It will take as much time to replace the JPA usage in the business logic than in the DAO it self.  If you need to do some JPA magic some where, you can abstract this part in separated class.  But 95% of JPA usage is simple CRUD which is straightforward to update.

Comment: I replaced `return new OracleCustomerDAO();` with `return (CustomerDAO) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/OracleCustomerDAO");` in `getCustomerDAO()` function. However it gives me a `NamingException`, which says **Name "comp/env/OracleCustomerDAO" not found.**

Comment: I also tried to put `@EJB(name="OracleCustomerDAO", beanInterface=CustomerDAO.class)` at the above of the `OracleDAOFactory` class definition, but it didn't help.

Comment: Where are you retrieving the EJB?  If it is not from an other EJB from the same container the JNDI name will be different.  The example and the test log on the example show which EJB has been created and there name.